# How can I search a particular website built over php for a particular word?

Tags: php

It is a multi page website and as I am no developer I have no clue how to search the same.  By the way I would not be able to share the link as it is an intranet website

Comment: well, if you're no developer, you either hire one or find a non-coding solution. for example an intern pressing `ctrl+f`

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your question, you want to find a particular word from a webpage. Use curl request or file_get_contents() to fetch the whole webpage content and then use regex to compare and find the word. But as you are not a developer this will be hard for you. So I would suggest you to hire a developer!